# Show/hide JSF2 form using <p:selectBooleanButton>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to show and hide component in my JSF 2-PrimeFaces application, please find my code below for the same:

```
 <p:outputLabel for="online_offer" value="Online offer#{msg._question_mark}" styleClass="font-size-1em font-weight-bold input-panel-main" />                                                                                                                                  
  <p:panel>
     <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <p:selectBooleanButton id="online_offer" value="#{QckPstBen.offer.isExpired}" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" onIcon="ui-icon-check" offIcon="ui-icon-close" >  
         <f:ajax event="click" render="@form" />
        </p:selectBooleanButton>
      </h:panelGrid>                                                                
   </p:panel>
    <h:outputLabel value="&nbsp;" />
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{QckPstBen.offer.isExpired}">
      <p:outputLabel for="website" value="Website/link to the offer#{msg._colon}" styleClass="font-size-1em font-weight-bold input-panel-main" />                                                                                                                                  
  <p:panel>
   <h:panelGrid columns="1">
          <p:inputText id="website" required="true" size="38" />
           <p:watermark for="website" value="www.discountbox.in" />
   </h:panelGrid>                                                                
  </p:panel>                                                                                                                                    
</h:panelGroup>
```

But it doesnt work, any clue

Comment: what do you wanna show ?? and what do you wanna hide?

Comment: I wanna show/hide stuffs inside <h:panelGroup> based on <p:selectBooleanButton> selection

Answer (score 3):

PrimeFaces components doesn't support `<f:ajax>`. Use `<p:ajax>` instead.

```
<p:selectBooleanButton ...>
    <p:ajax update="@form" />
</p:selectBooleanButton>
```

Note that I omitted the `event` attribute, it defaults here to `click` already.

Comment: Tried still it doesnt work BalusC. By the way how are you, I am a great fan of your JSF skills :)

Comment: `<h:form><p:selectBooleanButton value="#{bean.bool}"><p:ajax update="@form"/></p:selectBooleanButton><h:outputText value="foo" rendered="#{bean.bool}" /></h:form>`. The `#{bean.bool}` is a `boolean` property.

Answer (score 0):

Place rendered on children of `<h:panelGroup>` instead or place a container of some sort around it, for example p:panel.

Comment: Why? OP attempted to use `render="@form"` which should update the entire form.

Answer (score 0):

This may be OBE by now but...

When referencing the page bean, don't I recall in the #{} context, the convention of using lowercase for class names and method/attributes of the page bean (i.e. not #{QckPstBen.offer.isExpired} but #{qckPstBen.offer.isExpired}?